# Is it possible to call printer on a different network

Tags: java, network-printers

Currently our system is running on application server. and dot matrix printers connected to call centers computers.

Our system has receipt printing functionality.currently we open receipt in browser and send window.print() function to print receipt. we don't want to display receipt on browser and print.

Is it possible to call particular printer from back end ,our application is running on application server on centralize server. and dot matrix printers are connected to each computers.(call center).

Can you please give me advice regarding this. and also we have lesser printer connected to centralize computer ( different network ) and I also want to call that printer from back end ( application server)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question is about just allowing the users to print stuff on their own or you're doing the printing in the backend, but this might help:

first of all, you can use this 3rd party tool which does exactly that.: 
http://www.printhtml.com/

second of all, a little search revealed many command-line methods with which you can automate the printing process, do read here:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php

hope it helps.